# How can I return the return value of a functions whichs typ is a structure?

Tags: c, function, structure

I want to receive a return value of a function whichs typ is a struct. Thats what I have got:

Thats how I defined my struct

```
typedef struct _content {
    int length;
    char **lines;    
} content_t;
```

Function called in the main:

```
read_content("example.txt");
```

Thats my function called by the main:

```
content_t *read_content(char *filename)
{
    struct _content cont;

return cont;   //here I try to return my struct cont
}
```

Is it even possible to return a value in a function whichs type is a struct? How could I solve my problem?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have a type mismatch in your function.  It is returning a pointer to a `content_t` (i.e. a `content_t  *`) but you are returning an instance of a `content_t`.

You need to change the function to return a pointer to a `content_t`.  You can't however return the address of a local variable, i.e. `return &cont;`, because the variable will go out of scope when the function returns and the pointer value will be invalid when it is returned.  What you can do however is dynamically allocate memory in the function and return a pointer to that memory.

```
content_t *read_content(char *filename)
{
    content_t *cont = malloc(sizeof(*cont));
    ...
    return cont;
}
```

Don't forget to `free` the memory in the calling function.

Answer (score 0):

in

```
content_t *read_content(char *filename)
{
    struct _content cont;

    return cont;   //here I try to return my struct cont
}
```

you return a `struct _content` while a `struct _content *` is expected

yes you can return a `struct _content` rather than a pointer to :

```
content_t read_content(char *filename)
{
    struct _content cont;

    return cont;   //here I try to return my struct cont
}
```

but **warning** you get a copy of the struct but the *lines* are not duplicated

Answer (score 0):

```
content_t *read_content(char *filename)
{
    content_t *cont = malloc(sizeof(*cont));
    ...
    return cont;
}
```

or

```
content_t *read_content(char *filename, content_t *cont)
{
    ...
    return cont;
}
```

or

```
content_t *read_content(char *filename, content_t **cont)
{
    *cont = malloc(sizeof(**cont));
    ...
    return *cont;
}
```